# How can i set Bootstrap language manually?

Tags: asp.net, localization

last week i began developing an ASP.NET Page with Bootstrap (with LESS).

My website has an language switcher between German and English. This works fine for my own components.

But the Bootstrap sign-in form automatically uses the browser language. If an field is empty, i get a message to fill out all fields. I want to set the used language manually in all forms in Bootstrap.

Is this possible, or are there other options?

Thanks.

Edit:

here is my Code

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-signin" role="form">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">
            <asp:Localize ID="LocalizeHeading" runat="server" 
                meta:resourcekey="LocalizeHeadingResource1" Text="Anmeldung"></asp:Localize> 
       </h2>
        <input ID="InputUsername" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<%$ Resources: Authentification, PlaceHolderUsername %>" required autofocus>
        <input ID="InputPassword" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<%$ Resources: Authentification, PlaceHolderPassword %>" required>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> 
            <asp:Localize ID="LocalizeRememberMe" runat="server" 
                meta:resourcekey="LocalizeRememberMeResource1" Text="Anmeldung speichern"></asp:Localize>
        </label>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSignIn" runat="server" Text="Einloggen" 
              class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" 
              meta:resourcekey="ButtonSignInResource1" onclick="ButtonSignIn_Click" />
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I do not believe that Bootstrap sets any default message (since it has not a "sign-in" form). If you are using the `tooltip` javascript component please check the `data-original-title` attribute of your `<input>` field. If you are using a third-part library in order to generate the login code (as I suppose) you should mention which library are you using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use the example sign-in form from Bootstrap examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/.

The only third party library i use is JQuery.

Comment: Thank, now I understand the question - see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Bootstrap issue. The tooltip error is a default behaviour of [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API) so, at the very end, it generates from the browser. The error generates since the `input` tag has the attribute `required`, then the browser will try to ensure that you place any text on it.

Please check [changing the language of error message in required field in html5 contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form) - in particular Rikin's answer in order to set 
`setCustomValidity` message using javascript.