# How to change the default message of the required field in the popover of form-control in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <form class="form-asd" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">login</h2><hr />
    <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email"  required="" placeholder="username"data-error="enter username"></input>
    <label class="control-label"  for="username">password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password"  required=" " placeholder="Password"></input>
    <label class="checkbox"></label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

how can we change this default message of popover of the require field "Please fill out this field "to "please enter username"

Comment: [This codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeaqWY) does exactly this.

Comment: See also [changing the language of error message in required field in html5 contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form), nearly identical question, the only real difference being this question mentions bootstrap.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can use `setCustomValidity` function when `oninvalid` event occurs.

Like below:-

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" required="" 
    placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')">
</input>
```

#### Update:-

To clear the message once you start entering use `oninput="setCustomValidity('')` attribute to clear the message.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input class="form-control" type="email"  required="" placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Best explained here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: after i add this code i get my message shown, but then after entering some text in the input, i still have this message shown until I refresh.

Comment: in order to use this method, you need to clear the customValidity message after input, or it keeps showing that error message even if its valid. oninput="setCustomValidity('')" fixes this issue when used with oninvalid.

Comment: Is there any way to differentiate between a user leaving a field empty and a user inputing an invalid email? Can I edit both the required error message and the invalid email error message?

Comment: can this be done to all inputs not just in some pages ?

Comment: This is working but how to change: "Please include an '@' in the email address. '' is missing an '@'......   Any suggestions?

Comment: I really had lots of problems trying to implement his kind of solution ... I just couldn't ... I think it's messy.. I prefer to do some other way...

Comment: @Mritunjay sorry for commenting despite the answer was already accepted, is there any way to show the error message on the label instead of the input?
I already asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65030844/5792426

Answer (score 31):

Combination of Mritunjay and Bartu's answers are full answer to this question. I copying the full example.

```
<input class="form-control" type="email"  required="" placeholder="username"
 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')"
 oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></input>
```

Here,

**this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')"** - Display the custom message on invalidated of the field

**oninput="setCustomValidity('')"** - Remove the invalidate message on validated filed.

Answer (score 9):

And for all input and select:

```
$("input[required], select[required]").attr("oninvalid", "this.setCustomValidity('Required!')");
$("input[required], select[required]").attr("oninput", "setCustomValidity('')");
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change the text of the textarea. This method helped

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" required placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Error validate')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
  <br><br>
  <textarea placeholder="Ko’cha, uy, xonadon" name="address" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Majburiy maydon')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

$("input[required]").attr("oninvalid", "this.setCustomValidity('Say Somthing!')");

this work if you move to previous or next field by mouse, but by enter key, this is not work !!!