# Show custom messages with ng-required

Tags: angularjs

I am trying ng-required for the first time and it is solving my problem of validations. I just need to know how can I provide my custom messages with validations provided by ng-required. The fields on which ng-required is applied are dynamically generated with ng-repeat. So the custom messaged need to contain the field name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default message of the required field in the popover of form-control in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391078/how-to-change-the-default-message-of-the-required-field-in-the-popover-of-form-c)

Comment: the form fields are dynamic, i.e. some are dropdown and some are textboxes. This rendering is based on a condition. I need to have custom messages specific to a dropdown and textbox.

I saw the link given in above comment and applied the solution, but my ng-submit stopped working.

Comment: Can you please add a small code sample?