# setCustomValidity message styles on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am new to HTML. I am able to show custom message for html input field as mentioned at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391078/how-to-change-the-default-message-of-the-required-field-in-the-popover-of-form-c)
However, I want to show message on multiple lines e.g.

```
Message title:
    1. option 1 text
    2. option 2 text
```

I tried to insert **br** tag to message, but it is not working.

My code looks like as below:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="url" name="test_url" id="test_url" required="required" pattern="my_custom_url_pattern_goes_here" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('URL must be in one of the following format:\nFirst url example\nAnother url example')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?