# Why I need to click the button twice before it gets working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why I need to click the button twice before it gets working?
Function checks invalid input fields and passes sweetalert message when button is clicked.

```js
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function() {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit').on("click", function() {
      let valid = true;
      $('[required]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':invalid') || !$(this).val()) valid = false;
      })
      if (!valid) swal({
        title: "Good job",
        text: "You clicked the button!",
        type: "success"
      }, );
    })
  };
})(), true);
```

Comment: Because you're wrapping an event handler in a function in an event handler.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The code you've shared doesn't even contain any buttons

Comment: Thanks for response. May I ask you, how should I fix it?

Comment: The button type="submit" is in a form. And what have I tried? Actually nothing yet.

Comment: @NicoHaase Assuming, the HTML code for the button is fine, the problem is the use of this function that has the issue.

Comment: @node_modules assuming is a good start - sharing a runnable example is a better one ;)

Comment: you only add the click handler when the form emits invalid state. browser emits invalid state when you submit it. that means after first click you bind the function.

Comment: @cloned So, submit should go first?

Comment: this depends on what you want to do. do you want to check for invalid when you submit?  then yes.

Comment: You should only need one event handler - the *form* submit.   Then check if the form is valid or not within that handler.  But it's unclear what your comment (on the deleted answer) means: *using `invalid` to remove default browser popups when input fields are empty* - sounds like an XY Problem - what's the "default browser popup"?

Comment: Default is like some input is required and the browser shows bubble below it "please fill all the fields"

Comment: Using answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391078/how-to-change-the-default-message-of-the-required-field-in-the-popover-of-form-c) you can *remove* the default browser popup using `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' ')"` example: https://jsfiddle.net/78Lmcht4/

Comment: @freedomn-m Right, but it gives empty "bubble".

Comment: That's what I expected it would, but didn't for me in the fiddle, hence the suggestion.  Might be browser specific.

Comment: Great! I wrote those two event handlers as separate functions, one after another (submit first, invalid check second) and it seems working!