# HTML5 form required attribute language

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms, validation

Html5 form validation uses the browser (or os?) language, but I have an English website for mostly Duch users.
So all validation messages should be in English.

How can I change the language for these validation messages?

This is not a duplicate, I know I can set my own custom messages.
I don't need this, I just want to set the correct language, if that's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10754847/1138214

Comment: that's not the answer I need, it suggest a javascript solution, but I think it's also possible to just set the language (or at least it should)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the title tag to display the custom message:

```
 <input type="text" required title="Mijn aangepaste boodschap" />
```

EDIT

@Denis Chenu is right, this is not the correct solutions, this post has a correct javascript solution: [changing the language of error message in required field in html5 contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form)

So this is a duplicate and can be closed?

```js
document.getElementById('fname').setCustomValidity('Dit is verplicht kut');
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input required type="text" id="fname" name="fname" title="Vul dit veld in kut"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input required type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Still not the solution ;) this don't use the string by browser