# HTML type="email" error message language change

Tags: html, html-email

How do you change the language of the default error message you get with type="email"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing the language of error message in required field in html5 contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HTML oninvalid Event Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ev_oninvalid.asp)

```html
<form>
<input type="email"  required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, introduce una dirección de correo electrónico válida')"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only will your Message then use this:

```js
$('#text').on('change invalid', function() {
     this.setCustomValidity('Your message');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id="text" type="text" required />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```