# Oninvalid error message does not reset HTML

Tags: html

I have a form which takes an email as required input:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        Email Address*:
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" lang="en" title="Please enter a valid email address!" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address!')" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if for example the user presses enter or tries to submit the form without an email address, the following error correctly displays:
[image: Error message required]

But when the user afterwards correctly adds an email address, the required error does not reset, thus not allowing the form to be submitted:

[image]

Comment: Include your Minimum reproduce able sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you reset `setCustomerValidity`?

Comment: I know there is a way by using a lot of JQuery code. The only reason I used the `setCustomValidity` is because my input box standard required error message won't respond to `lang="en"` or `<html lang="en">` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form).

Answer (score 0):

Resetting `oninvalid` with an `onchange` did the trick for me!

```
            <input
                oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('your message')"
                onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
            />
```